# Does java file read speed changes with number of files under the same folder

Tags: java, windows, file, directory, read-write

Hello my question is simple consider these two senarios:
1)A folder with 300.000 files in it
2)A folder with 30 folders each has 10.000 files in it.

Now im randomly selecting 1000 of those files and try to reach them using with java, will there be any speed difference between those two senarios?

Note that I know the exact files names in 1 and exact folder/filename in 2. So finding the correct folder in 30 will be O(1).

Comment: Did you try it? Did you get any difference?

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to Java; possibly related to the operating system you're actually running on, and generally speaking, not likely to make much difference overall if any.

Comment: @il_raffa No I haven't tried.

Comment: Finding the correct file in the folder will be *O(log N)* or *O(N)* depending on how directories are implemented the operating system. Java neither knows nor cares how many files are in the directory, but the operating system does.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can use windows or linux if any can perform better. The reason for java is, I will be using java to read the files not the explorer.exe itself or linux file manager etc.

Comment: @KaanOğuzhan the only thing to do is test it.

Comment: @EJP So to make it clear as long as I use Java and give it the correct file pattern. It will take the same time even on different directory implementation on different operating systems.

Comment: No, the timing will be different on different operating systems, but it doesn't matter if you use Java, C++ or python.

Comment: @KaanOğuzhan That is exactly what I have just contradicted. Read what I wrote. It can't be constant time if it depends on *N*, and it depends on the operating system, not on Java.

Comment: @EJP sorry for my english understanding mistakes its not my first language and thank you for your answer.